# Given matrix, A, having more columns than rows, is it possible for a vector b, which is in same domain as columns, to not belong to col(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here, $A$ has $5$ columns w/ $4$ rows. $b$ is a given $4\times1$ vector.

Is it possible for $b$ not to belong to $\mathrm{col}(A)$? I am confused because I know that $\mathrm{col}(A)=\mathrm{span}\{\text{columns of} A\}$ and b/c there are more columns than rows, columns of A are linearly dependent. Wouldn't this mean that $\mathrm{col}(A)$ spans the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^4$? If so, how can it be that after solving $Ax=b$ I ended up with something that cannot be (e.g. 1=0). Because there are more columns than rows, does $\mathrm{col}(A)$ no longer cover all of $\mathbb{R}^4$? Thanks in advance.

$A=\pmatrix{1&0&2&0&-1\\0&1&3&0&2\\0&0&0&3&9\\1&0&2&0&-1}$

$%\pmatrix{1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\2&3&0&2\\0&0&3&0\\-1&2&9&-1}^T$

$b=\pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\2}$

Comment: Does this have to do with the fact that in A, after reducing to echelon form there will only be 3 pivot points hence the basis of col(A) will really be made up of only 3 vectors instead of the 4 needed to cover all of R4?

Comment: I find it hard to read your question, no MathJax and it's written a bit messy. Anyway, isn't the zero matrix an example?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am not very familiar with the platform, it's my first time posting. I did work it out for Ax=0 and there were no contradictions and I was able to find a vector for x that satisfied the problem. My concern is why this particular b = [1 1 1 2] <transpose>, when put into Ax=b, causes the bottom row, after reducing, to give me 0=1.

Comment: Just because there are more columns than rows doesn't imply the columns are linearly independent. In fact it implies that at least one of them is linearly dependent. Another simple example would be if all the columns were exactly the same vector. Then the column space would only span a one dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1):

$\dim \mathrm{col} (A)=\dim \mathrm{row} (A)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$

Since in your case the first row of $A$ equals the last one you got $\mathrm{rank}(A)\le3 <4$ and therefore $\mathrm{col} (A)$ doesn't span $\mathbb{R}^4$, i.e. $ \mathrm{col}(A)\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^4$. Thus there is $b\in \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $b\not\in \mathrm{col}(A)$.